# recreate schema on each restart

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, ebean

I have a test server at clever-cloud.com where Git automatically pushes on any new commits.

The problem is in case of any model changes I get **Database 'default' is in an inconsistent state** error.

The problem is that on server play is running in PROD, not in DEV mode. So it's not offering me drop and regenerate the schema(it only offers to generate schema the first time, but not to regenerate it later).

How can I drop and recreate schema from Play app itself? I already have working code which performs it.  But I don't know where to hang it.

I've tried putting in to Global.onStart or Global.beforeStart, but there it goes into the loop with Ebean creating tables and my code dropping all them again and again.

How to make it run one and only time after restart and then allow Ebean to generate schema?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have two problems here, first, in production mode you can force adding evolutions by adding `-DapplyEvolutions=true` to your start command (check clever-cloud docs how to do that).

Other thing is much worse... You SHOULD NOT overwrite your database in production. Keep in mind that you are loosing all data as evolutions just drops existing DB and creates it from scratch.  Instead you should avoid automatically created evolution (by removing two first lines of `1.sql` file and start writing you custom evolutions (`2.sql`, `3.sql` etc).

On the quite other hand, we decided to switch to [MyBatis Migrations](http://mybatis.github.io/migrations/index.html) for applying changes at the remote servers, it does almost the same job as Evolutions, anyway is little bit more flexible (it's standalone, not Play plugin)

Comment: Thx for you reply, biesior! Actually I have "applyEvolutions.default=true" in my clevercloud.conf. Also I've added it to sbt.json, so now it has a string: "goal": "-Dconfig.resource=clevercloud.conf -DapplyEvolutions=true -DapplyEvolutions.default=true". But still it fails to start with "Database 'default' is in an inconsistent state". Any ideas why? Of course I agree with you on production server. In my case it's still a development server which just deploys a snapshot after a push from Git. It runs in PROD mode just because clever cloud don't have any settings about that.

Comment: That happens when previous evolutions was applied with errors, tbh have no idea how to resolve it on remote host (maybe database purge?), that's the one of reasons why we decided to standalone MyBatis Migrations. Other thing is that you can probably connect to DB with some GUI and try to fix row(s) in play_evolutions table

Comment: Yeah, well from GUI I can manually drop schema and create new one. The idea is to make an automatic pipeline where after a commit I have a working copy on the server in 4-5 minutes.

Comment: yes, I understand what you want :) automatic pipeline is a point, anyway `inconsistent state` is result of problems with applying evos, when you create own evolution they contain only additional stuff, so these errors should not happen (you should not send it if not tested)

Comment: I've cleaned DB manually and allowed Ebean to generate schema from scratch. Now when I add new model classes, of new fields and push them to clever-cloud it compiles perfectly but without any attempt to evolve the DB. PersistenceException error comes when I'm trying to save an instance of a new model class which has no corresponding table. It seems that applyEvolutions=true flag is only valid for the first evolution while in PROD.